# Move my.cnf to Different Mount Point on MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I am working on a RHEL 6.6 server which runs MySQL version 5.7.17 which I had installed by the following command:

```
yum install mysql-server
```

My client want me to move the `my.cnf` from it's default location `/etc/my.cnf` to `/app/mysql/my.cnf`. If I move, the mysql server fails.

I cannot find any way to do this.

If anyone know the way, please help me.

Comment: Please read this part of the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html You can export MYSQL_HOME

Answer (score 3):

Pass `--defaults-file=/app/mysql/my.cnf` when mysql is launched.

Another option is to create a symbolic link to /etc/my.cnf:

```
ln -s /app/mysql/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf
```

Comment: I use "service mysqld start" to start the server. It does not accept that paramener. In which command should I use this parameter?

Comment: See my second option.  That might be a better way of doing things anyway.

Comment: I am sorry but as per client, symlink will not do.